# org.hibernate.annotations vs. javax.persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it a bad idea to use the annotations from the

> javax.persistence package

instead of using the

> org.hibernate.annotations annotations

I know that using `javax.peristence` does introduce yet another dependency. But if I ignore that, what are the pros/cons?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Quite the opposite.

Hibernate is an implementation of the Java Persistence API, and where possible, you should use the standard annotations (in javax.persistence). This way, you could theoretically run your code on other JPA implementations.

Only when you need Hibernate-specific functionality should you use the Hibernate annotations.

The extra dependency is only on the JPA interface/annotation jar files and very light.

Comment: so its possible to mix annotations from these packages (javax.persistence & org.hibernate.annotations) withing an @Entity

Comment: you can use jpa entities when you want to work with hibernate functions.  in my experience you can't mix and match jpa/hibernate among all of your entities.

Comment: It depends. I have been using Hibernate for a long time, and there is no reason to switch.

Answer (score 7):

Another cons in:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/

where this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
  cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE }, 
  mappedBy = "stock")
public Set<StockDailyRecord> getStockDailyRecords() {
    return this.stockDailyRecords;
}
```

with this:

```
stockDailyRecords.setStock(stock);        
stock.getStockDailyRecords().add(stockDailyRecords);

session.save(stock);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

won't work as `@OneToMany` is from JPA, it expects a JPA cascade – `javax.persistence.CascadeType`. However when you save it with Hibernate session, `org.hibernate.engine.Cascade` will do the following check:

```
if ( style.doCascade( action ) ) {
```

and Hibernate save process will causing a `ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE` action, but the JPA will pass a `ACTION_PERSIST` and `ACTION_MERGE`, it will not match and cause the cascade to fail to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I used `javax.persistence` annotation, and when I replaced Tomcat 6.0 with my Glass Fish, then Tomcat 6.0 included another javax.persistence package that messed everything. I don't think it's a good idea to use `javax.persistence` annotation. God know what the hell happened with Tomcat and `javax.persistence`!

Comment: This answer is not real helpful as it does not describe the conditions of the change, the exact symptoms, nor a possible solution. What files changed, what were the errors, and what were the new jars?

Answer (score 0):

Officially recommended to mix JPA and Hibernate annotations in the case of setting cascading options, see
[Hibernate docs. 2.4.7. Cascade](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-cascade). If you using only JPA annotations, in case of unidirectional mapping (no field of Foo type in Employer.java) you still getting "cannot save transient object Employer" in the call session.SaveOrUpdate. Cure is using hibernate-style @Cascade together with cascade={...}:

```
class Foo {
     @OneToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
     @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REPLICATE)
     public Collection<Employer> getEmployers()
...
}
```